# Magento SOAP exception in C#

Tags: c#, magento, soap

I am trying to connect magento SOAP api using C# and my code sample is

```
        MagentoService mservice = new MagentoService();          
        mservice.Url = "http://<address>/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap";
        mservice.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
       string mlogin = mservice.login("username", "pass@word");
```

I am using Web refrence and megento version 1.8.2
after calling log method 
i got error

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http:///magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "http:///magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=

Comment: try using this URL only http://<address>/api/v2_soap

Comment: not working got error The request failed with an empty response.

Comment: my address is in browser:<localhost>/magento/index.php

Comment: If your server does not support redirects try with this url `http://<host>/api.php?type=v2_soap`

Comment: Can you give me completed code